# Play PlayReady 4.0+ Test Content with dash.js

Tags: codec, drm, dash.js, playready

Im trying to test out the sample streams given in [PlayReady test content](http://testweb.playready.microsoft.com/Content/Content4X). Im using dash.js as the player and testing in Edge(Dev).

Im getting this error at the playback.

> [61][Stream] audioCodec (audio/mp4;codecs="ac-3") is not supported

My code

```
var player, video;

const config = {
  serverURL: 'http://test.playready.microsoft.com/service/rightsmanager.asmx?cfg=(persist:false,sl:150)'
};
const protData = {
  "com.microsoft.playready": config
};
const url = "https://test.playready.microsoft.com/media/dash/APPLEENC_CBCS_BBB_1080p/1080p.mpd";

video = document.querySelector("video");
player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
player.setProtectionData(protData);
player.initialize(video, url, true);
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dash.js defers all media decoding to the browser. The player tests for AC-3 support in the browser media engine by calling `MediaSource.isTypeSupported ('audio/mp4; codecs="ac-3"')`. On whatever build of Edge you are using, this is returning `false`.

Returns `true` here on Windows 10, Edge 44.18362.267.0, EdgeHTML 18.18362.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely a good initiative for me. 
Im testing on a Mac and none of the browsers seems to support ac-3 for Mac. Initially I tested on Edge Dev Version 78.0.262.0 and then I downloaded Edge Beta (for Mac) Version 77.0.235.20 and tested but no good.
Would installing codecs for OS make any impact or do codecs have to be supported from the browser engine itself?